# XSL with multiple templates

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to create an XSL that transforms a XML using the following steps:

1. Identify if the element under the root "properties" has a name starting with 'foo'. If it does not start with 'foo', delete the element.
2. Create new elements called 'entry' with an attribute 'key' that equals the name of the elements starting with 'foo'.

The process can also be in reverse order of specified steps if that seems to be easier.

**XML Document**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<properties>
    <oof>AAA</oof>
    <bar>BBB</bar>
    <foobar>CCC</foobar>
    <barfoo>DDD</barfoo>
    <foofoofoobar>EEE</foofoofoobar>
</properties>
```

**My XSLT that only changes element to entry**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
     <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="properties/*">
     <entry>
         <xsl:attribute name="key" select="name()"/>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
     </entry>
  </xsl:template>
```

When I try using another template `<xsl:template match="properties[not(contains(name(), 'foo'))]"/>`, it does not get performed after the 'entry' element template. If I do a template before the entry template, the entry template is not performed.

**Desired output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<properties>
    <entry key="foobar">CCC</entry>
    <entry key="foofoofoobar">EEE</entry>
</properties>
```

Your help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

I was able to create `<xsl:template match="entry[not(contains(@*, 'foo'))]"/>` which will delete entry elements that do not contain foo which isnt entirely what I want but is another step in the right direction. However if I put it all in one XSLT document, only the first template will run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming the other template looks like this for the purposes of the question

```
<xsl:template match="properties[not(contains(name(), 'foo'))]" />
```

This is matching the `properties` element, and as the name "properties" does not contain the text "foo", the condition is true, and so processing effectively stops here (i.e `properties` does not get copied, and none of the child `entry` nodes get matched).

You probably want to do this (I've swapped from `contains` to `starts-with` as that matches your requirement)

```
<xsl:template match="properties/*[not(starts-with(name(), 'foo'))]" />
```

But.... There is an issue here with template priority.

The element `properties/bar` (for example) would matched by both your templates, so the XSLT has to invoke [Conflict Resolution for Template Rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#conflict) (If the description seems too complicated, check out http://www.lenzconsulting.com/how-xslt-works/#priority instead). What this means is that both your templates have the same priority; 0.5. What generally happens in this case, is the processor will use the last matching template in the XSLT, although some processors may signal the error.

To resolve this you can either give the template a priority

```
<xsl:template match="properties/*[not(starts-with(name(), 'foo'))]" priority="0.6" />
```

Or you could add a condition to the other template

```
<xsl:template match="properties/*[starts-with(name(), 'foo')]">
```

Or you could combine the two templates into one...

```
<xsl:template match="properties/*">
  <xsl:if test="starts-with(name(), 'foo')">
    <entry key="{name()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </entry>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Try this XSLT (which uses the priority method)

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
     <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="properties/*[not(starts-with(name(), 'foo'))]" priority="0.6" />

  <xsl:template match="properties/*">
     <entry key="{name()}">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
     </entry>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As a bonus, this XSLT also makes use of [Attribute Value Templates](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#attribute-value-templates) to create the `key` attribute on the `entry` elements.

Comment: This is fantastic! Works great. One issue is that when it deletes nodes that do not start with 'foo' a white space s left in between nodes. How can I remove the whitespace?

Comment: Strip out white space using `xsl:strip-space`. See http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyH9rMB

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for your assistance on my XSL. This is looking great!